# Adding files to a zip folder using batch

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, zip

I am making a program using batch that will boost pc performance one of the things it does is edit the registry and just before it does it exports the registry to 5 file using the following code:

```
@ECHO OFF
reg export HKLM %~dp0hklm.reg > nul
echo hklm
reg export HKCU %~dp0hkcu.reg > nul
echo hkcu
reg export HKCR %~dp0hkcr.reg > nul
echo hkcr
reg export HKU  %~dp0hku.reg > nul
echo hku
reg export HKCC %~dp0hkcc.reg > nul
echo hkcc
reg export HKEY %~dp0hkey.reg > nul
echo hkey
pause
```

When I do this I get 5 files that add up to 250 MB and this it too big so I put them in a zip file and it added up to 16 MB so its a good idea to compress them. My question is how do I export the 5 files to one zip file instead. Can any one help.

Comment: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_files_zip.php - check this...

Comment: Doesn't `reg` have limitations with certain keys in the registry, with restricted permissions?

Comment: Yes but I can elevate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check the [zipjs.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/zipjs.bat) indtroduced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28043589/how-can-i-compres-zip-and-uncopress-unzip-files-and-folders-with-batch-f)  :

```
// adds content to a zip file
zipjs.bat addToZip -source C:\some_file -destination C:\myDir\myZip.zip\InzipDir -keep no
zipjs.bat addToZip -source  C:\some_file -destination C:\myDir\myZip.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

Windows 7 does not provide command line access to its native zip functionality. However, it is available to VB or JS. See this superuser question https://superuser.com/questions/110991/can-you-zip-a-file-from-the-command-prompt-using-only-windows-built-in-capabili on how to use it for your purpouses.